# Can I change Google cloud functions working directory?

Tags: python, function, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a python script that works locally. It processes text files and imports rows to a google sheet. I am trying to run this script using cloud functions and a cloud storage bucket to automate the process.

Can I change the working directory to the bucket directory? Or do I have to download the files from the bucket as text to process them and run the code?

If I can change the working directory, the script should run as is and I won't have to use the storage module from google.cloud (I am assuming).

If I do have to download the files, I will have to figure out how to use glob.glob() to loop through the files in the directory and only process certain files.

Anyone know the best way to go about this?

I am currently able to download a file and process it but, I have to call out the file name explicitly and cannot use glob.glob to find files that match a certain pattern.

Below you can see, the first half of this code where I am able to download the file and start processing it.

Within the function, you can see how it would work typically if I could just point to the directory the files are in.

```
from google.cloud import storage
from cloudevents.http import CloudEvent
import functions_framework
import glob
import os
#Can I change the working directory?
#os.chdir(bucket)
#print(os.getcwd())

# Instantiates a client
client = storage.Client()
bucket_name = 'working_files'
bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)

#This will show me all of the files in the directory
#blobs = client.list_blobs('working_files')
#for blob in blobs:
#  print(blob.name)

##I have to call out the specific file name for this to work.
blob = bucket.blob("explicit_file_name.txt")
blob = blob.download_as_text()
#example of the work we will do in the file
Main_DF = blob[50:100]
##Splitting the data and cleaning out the = dividers
Main_DF = [row.strip().replace('=','').split(', ') for row in Main_DF]
##Getting rid of whitespace
Main_DF = [row[0].split() for row in Main_DF]
print(Main_DF)

@functions_framework.cloud_event
def hello_gcs(cloud_event: CloudEvent):
  ##example of how the code would typically work if I could just iterate through files in the direcotry
  Daily_File = [f for f in glob.glob("*common_identifier*")]
  if Daily_File == []:
     
      print("No relevant file found")
      #Daily_File
  else:
    print(Daily_File)
```

Comment: "Can I change the working directory to the bucket directory?" - No, it is not possible. From the best of my GCP understanding. There is a fundamental paradigm difference....

Comment: "Can I change the working directory to the bucket directory?" - No, as @al-dann said. But, you can cheat! For that, you have to use Cloud Run, instead of Cloud Functions. And then, mount a [GCSFuse volume on Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/services/cloud-storage-volume-mounts). GCSFuse wrap the Linux system call in API call to access Cloud Storage transparently. Like that, you can work as a local directly, but with GCS!

Comment: Ok, @guillaumeblaquiere maybe I will try that. I thought the approach with cloud functions would be easiest but maybe it is not for my use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is re-architect the code and make use of the Cloud Storage library for Python. You have already started to use it. You can then process file contents from there. I'd recommend to use the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) as a starting point, as it contains many good examples.